# Solver (baron) did not exit normally

Tags: python, optimization, solver, pyomo, ampl

I install Baron solver on windows and I use pyomo in Spyder. I move baron.exe to current directory
when I run my code, this error appears:

```
Solver log file: 'C:\Users\~\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpumg5hxvr.baron.log'
Solver solution file: 'C:\Users\~\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpbmx1pfpt.baron.soln'
Solver problem files: ('C:\\Users\\~\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\tmpygo80gcy.pyomo.bar',)
C:\Users\~\baron.exe: can't open C:\Users\~\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpygo80gcy.pyomo.bar.nl
ERROR: Solver (baron) returned non-zero return code (1)
ERROR: See the solver log above for diagnostic information.
Traceback 
ApplicationError: Solver (baron) did not exit normally
```

But There is not the log file: `C:\Users\~\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpumg5hxvr.baron.log`
How can I fix this problem?
Thanks for your helps in advance.

Comment: Try adding the `tee=True` option to your solve statement in order to see some more information about the solver’s actions.

Comment: @gmavrom I had added it. My code was: `opt.solve(instance,keepfiles=True,tee=True)`

Comment: This might have something to do with Pyomo misidentifying the executable as an ASL solver. What does your invocation of `SolverFactory` look like?

Comment: @QiChen Thanks for your reply. My invocation is like this: `from pyomo.opt import SolverFactory`    `opt = SolverFactory('baron')
opt.solve(instance,keepfiles=True,tee=True)`

Comment: try `opt=SolverFactory('baron', solver_io='bar')` or `opt=SolverFactory('baron', executable='C:\\Users\\~\\baron.exe')`

Comment: @QiChen I tried it but unfortunately it doesn't  work. I got the same previous error.

Comment: Only thing I've got is a potential windows file permissions issue. To clarify, is a file generated `C:\Users\~\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpygo80gcy.pyomo.bar.nl`?

Comment: @QiChen No. There is not such file. The error says cannot open this file.

Answer (score 0):

I met the same problem today. I solved the problem by changing the solver name 'baron' to 'Baron'

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because the solver didn't execute the algorithm correctly, and I also had this problem in my implementation because I incorrectly used `exec()` to dynamically add constraints and an objective function. When I put all the variables involved in the dynamic definition in the `exec()` function, this error doesn't happen again.